# Django -south - Checking for existing table within migration

Tags: django, django-south, django-migrations

Some of my migrations should be run only when certain conditions are met - mostly because of the buggy nature of using south to migrate a django.contrib. needed when converting to our own user model. But since those migrations should run automatically I can't count on "--fake" - Sometime I need to run them, and sometime not - depending if the relation `auth_permissions`, for example, exists. 
can I use the south/django orm in a migration `forward` section to check for an existing relation and run the migration in a`if clause`?

I tried using try/except in the migration but it seems to cause an error (currently can't reproduce that, I don't have this code any more)

How can I achieve that?
Thanks for the help!

Using Django 1.6.4 and south 0.8.4